# Display posts in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to display my first two posts initially in two columns and the other three in three columns. See screenshot below:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
<section class="cases">
    <div class="container">
        <h4 class="title">Cases</h4>

        <?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'cases',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $the_query -> have_posts() ):

        ?>

        <div class="row">

            <?php
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
                $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );
            ?>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                <?php the_field('case_content') ?>
                <a href="#case-<?= $slug ?>" class="button">Bekijk de case</a>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>

        </div>

        <?php endif;?>

    </div>
</section>
```

And this is what I end up with:

[image]

How to proceed from here?

Comment: I would recommend you to make the markup for all 6 elements the same and on the same level and then style them differently with css. Have a look at flexbox. You can make the first 2 elements 50% width and the others 33%. Use media queries to make them responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like explained in my comment I would recommend you to make the markup for all 6 elements the same and on the same level and then style them differently with css. Have a look at flexbox. You can make the first 2 elements 50% width and the others 33%. Use media queries to make them responsive.
Here is some basic example code:

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 900px;
}

.item {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 background: #ddd;
 flex: 1 1 50%;
 min-height: 200px;
}

.item:nth-child(3),
.item:nth-child(4),
.item:nth-child(5) {
 flex: 1 1 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

This should be a good starting point to make this layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, going to try it out :)